# CSS rule for :checked <label> separated from its INPUT

Tags: css, css-selectors

For a normal radio button as

```
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios"value="yes">
<label for="radio2">Yes</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="no">
<label for="radio3">Yes</label>
```

the CSS of the `checked` label can be set with this selector

```
input:checked + label {
}
```

but if the `label` is not immediately after the `input`? For example, if placing `input`s and `label`s within a html table.

`for` and `id` attributes connect `label` and `input`, as input will be selected by clicking on the label. I wonder if it is possible to use this connection for setting the CSS rules of a label of checked input.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is none. You cannot use the values of HTML attributes "dynamically" in CSS selectors (although you *can* use them statically, as in `label[for=radio2]`).

If you want to style labels based on what they are labeling you will either have to give them some attribute that enables you to distinguish them (e.g. a class) or else use JavaScript.

Comment: then how to set CSS for `selected`?

Comment: `:selected` is [not a valid CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: sorry, I meant `:checked`

Comment: @All: There's no way to do that with CSS, you will have to use JavaScript (when the checkbox is checked, find the associated label and do something with it).

Answer (score 1):

Assume that CSS is like a one way door, once you open it, you can either roam in that room, get in another door, but than you won't be able to come out, same way, if the elements are not direct descendent to their parent, or the levels of nesting are different, you cannot select them at any way as of now.

So assume, that if the elements are not adjacent to each other, but they both are at same nesting levels under a common parent or the `label` is child of another nested element which is nested at the same level as your `checkbox` does

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" />
   <p>Hello</p>
   <label>Color me on check</label>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4byyJ/)

So you can chain the elements like the above.

---

Same level adjacent elements, you can target the further nested element like

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + p + div > label {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4byyJ/1/)

---

But the moment you wrap an element around `input type checkbox` the selector will fail as I said, you cannot come out of the room once you are in

<s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4byyJ/2/)</s>

---

So it's like

```
Parent
Checkbox    Level 1                    
Div         Level 1                    input[type=checkbox]:checked + div
Label       Level 1                    input[type=checkbox]:checked + div + label
   Span     Level 2 (Child of label)   input[type=checkbox]:checked + div + label > span
   i        Level 2 (Adjacent to span) input[type=checkbox]:checked + div + label > span + i
```

Fail Cases

```
Parent
Div             Level 1
   Checkbox     Level 2 (Child of div)
Span            Level (Adjacent to div) You won't be able to select this on check of checkbox
```